# AWS S3 403 Access Denied from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am facing this issue where the S3 Buckets on say Account A are accessible from external IPs(like my laptop), but not from an EC2 instance of another Account B.

I have granted full s3 access to the keys I am using from the laptop and the EC2 instance.Are there any IP level permissions that need to be granted specifically for EC2 instances?

Attached S3 IAM policy for the user :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

P.S: I am aware of cross account access permissions, but the thing is I want the EC2 instance to be treated like "just another request" from a public IP.

Comment: what user is this policy attached to? in which account? are you using access keys?

Comment: An IAM user in Account  A.Yes, I am using access keys for the same user (in account A)

Comment: Can you show example code how do use `aws-sdk` please?

Comment: Check this out: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was we had a VPC endpoint setup which had restrictions on bucket access. Adding permissions to access the Account A buckets as a new statement in the VPC endpoint policy fixed the issue.

Example:

```
{
    "Sid": "StmtXXXXX",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
    "AWS": "XXXXXX"   (ARN of the IAM user in Account A whose keys are being used)
    },
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
```

Comment: VPC endpoints work by hijacking all of the traffic bound for all of the public IP addresses associated with all of S3 within the same region, in your VPC route tables... hence the reason the VPC endpoint can control access the way it does, even for buckets from another account.

Comment: Yeah never realized that would be the case ! Spent a full night debugging the issue.